# Show text in labels from SRT file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, label

I have `.srt` file and I need to show content text if time equals timestamp.

example :

```
1
00:02:05,600 --> 00:02:08,840
line 1
line 2

2
00:02:09,280 --> 00:02:13,440
line 1
line 2
....
```

I need to show content like `line1` and `line2` in `label1`.

```
if time 00:02:05,600 = timestamp from srt file 00:02:05,600 then 
label1.visible = true
label1.text=line1 & line2

if time 00:02:08,840 = timestamp from srt file 00:02:08,840 then 
label1.visible = false
```

Comment: Just providing us with your requirement is not a question. You have to show us what you have done in order to implement it and explain exactly how the result doesn;t match your expectation. If you've made no effort then you haven't encountered an issue yet. The fact that you have no badges indicates that you ignored the prompt to take the tour and learn how the site works at registration. Spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to post a proper question, edit your question to conform to the rules and you'll have a better chance of it being answered rather than closed.

Comment: And why in your pseudo code the first if is `true` and the second one is `false`? The left and right operands are equal in both!

Comment: okay thanks for yours replay about true and false because i have 100 line i need to show label in start time and false if end time

Comment: @jmcilhinney sory im verry bad in english i cant read if you have arabic help please let me

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326128/how-do-i-parse-a-srt-subtitle-file/59347650#59347650) might be useful.